# Center axis.title and legend position relative to main plot in ggside

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using [ggside](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggside/ggside.pdf) to plot a contour plot of data and a line plot together in one graph. This works as expected, but for me there is a problem with the position of the x and y axis title as well as the legend.

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (!require("ggside")) install.packages("ggside")

# get data

# contour

set.seed(230529)

z <- runif(n = 100, min = -5, max = 20)
x <- y <- seq(1, length(z)/10, 1)
tmp <- expand.grid(x, y)
x <- tmp[,1]
y <- tmp[,2]

df.1 <- data.frame(x, y)
df.1$z <- z
df.1$level <- as.numeric(df.1$z)

# line plot

y <- runif(n = length(z)/10, min = -5, max = 20)
x <- seq(1, length(y), 1)

df.2 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

# plot data

ggplot(df.1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = sum(range(x))/2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = sum(range(x))/2) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_xsideline(data = df.2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_ysideline(data = df.2, aes(x = y, y = x), orientation = "y")
```

[image: wrong centering]

As indicated with the black lines in the graph, these parts of the plot are centered relative to the whole plot (main plot + side plots).

**Question**

Is there an option for ggside to align these parts relative to the main plot?

If not,is there a way, e.g., using `hjust` etc. to shift these parts automatically?

**Update**

As mentioned in the question, `hjust` and `vjust` can do the job. When setting the size of the side plot using `ggside.panel.scale`.

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (!require("ggside")) install.packages("ggside")

# get data

# contour

set.seed(230529)

z <- runif(n = 100, min = -5, max = 20)
x <- y <- seq(1, length(z)/10, 1)
tmp <- expand.grid(x, y)
x <- tmp[,1]
y <- tmp[,2]

df.1 <- data.frame(x, y)
df.1$z <- z
df.1$level <- as.numeric(df.1$z)

# line plot

y <- runif(n = length(z)/10, min = -5, max = 20)
x <- seq(1, length(y), 1)

df.2 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

# plot data

ggplot(df.1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = sum(range(x))/2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = sum(range(x))/2) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.4375),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 0.4375),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.justification = c(1,0.4375),
        aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_xsideline(data = df.2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_ysideline(data = df.2, aes(x = y, y = x), orientation = "y") +
  theme(ggside.panel.scale = 0.125,
        ggside.axis.text = element_blank(),
        ggside.axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

**New Question**

Is there a way to access the value for `ggside.panel.scale` automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the value ... automatically". Are you asking how to determine the value that will work? If so, how did you come up with 0.125 in your example?

Comment: Hello @Excelsior, Currently centering text labels such as title relative to the main plot instead of the entire plotting region has not been explored in the `ggside` package. At the moment, development for `ggside` has become slow due to school, so I cannot guarantee a quick implementation. However, it is documented in `?ggside-theme` that `ggside.panel.scale` defaults to `0.1`. Perhaps you may use this knowledge to help inform how much `hjust` should be.

Answer (score 1):

Set the value for my_scale.

```
my_scale <- 0.125
adjust <- ((1 / my_scale) / ((1 / my_scale) +1)) / 2


ggplot(df.1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = z, color = after_stat(level))) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = sum(range(x))/2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = sum(range(x))/2) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = adjust),
        axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = adjust),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.justification = c(1,adjust), 
        aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_xsideline(data = df.2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_ysideline(data = df.2, aes(x = y, y = x), orientation = "y") +
  theme(ggside.panel.scale = my_scale,
        ggside.axis.text = element_blank(),
        ggside.axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I define the value for the scaling factor of the side plot, this works fine. Now the question is, if I can access the metric of the scaling without defining it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not following the question. Are you looking for ggplot_build()?